# Restrict Django admin to only allow super-users

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm currently building an Django app that is using an LDAP authentication backend. Because of this all ldap authenticated users are also allowed to login to the admin interface. Is there a way I can lock down the admin interface to only super users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That shouldn't be the case. Just because there's a user account doesn't mean it can be used to login to the admin.

In order to access the admin, `User.is_staff == True`, and it's not by default. Simply only set the flag on actual users you want to be able to login to the admin, and you're good.

If for some reason LDAP users have been added with `is_staff` set to `True`, you can simply do:

```
User.objects.update(is_staff=False)
```

And then, just for the users you want to grant access to:

```
u=User.objects.get(username='admin_user')
u.is_staff = True
u.save()
```